# Custom setter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to do something like this:

```
public void setContentView(int resId) {
    this.content = itemView.findViewById(resId);
}
```

but don't know how. Any solutions to fix my code below?

```
private var contentView: AppCompatEditText? = null
set(value: Int) {field = v.findViewById(value)} // value in setter is AppCompatEditText? type not Int
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
fun setView(resID: Int){
  foo = view.findViewById(resID)
}
```

Edit: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: this is not a setter in kotlin

Comment: Yes! That's great and simple example :)                                                                     fun setContentEditText(resId: Int) = v.findViewById<AppCompatEditText>(resId)

Comment: Yeah I just did what you asked "I want to do something like this:", which is not a setter. So yay, a checkmark...and a -1. LOL